# How to parse dynamic JSON with Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have dynamic JSON, here is example: http://pastebin.com/QMWRZTrD

How I can parse it with Retrofit?

I failed to generate POJO classes, since I have dynamic fields like "5411" and "5412".

**EDIT**:

I solved it by using Map, since first value is always integer, and second is list of objects.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("history.php")
Observable<Map<Integer, List<Vehicle>>> getHistory(@Field("uredjaji") String vehicleId, @Field("startDate") String startDATE, @Field("endDate")
```

Comment: you can use a `Map` instead of a POJO.

Comment: Post answer, since I solved it by your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Map` to serialize and deserialize it in case of Random keys. 
`Observable<Map<Integer, List<YourObject>>>`

Answer (score 2):

You can get retrofit api call to return String in your RestApi Interface like

```
Call<String> method(@Path(..)...);
```

And for that to work you would need to add the scalars converter factory to where you create your Retrofit object.
First you would need to import it:

```
compile  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
```

And then add it:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl("https://your.base.url/")
    .build();
```

And then in onResponse

```
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String,List<SomeClass>>() {}.getType(); // define generic type
        Map<String,List<SomeClass>> result= gson.fromJson(response.body(), mapType);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Also,check out [this site](https://futurestud.io/) it has great tutorials on Retrofit.

Comment: Hvala Dusane, sad cu probati :)

Comment: Rijesio sam na osnovu mape, iako je ovaj tvoj nacin zanimjiv, nisam znao da moze ovako. Pozdrav i hvala!

Comment: Nema na cemu, ja sam mislio da nece moci da deserijalizuje automatski pa sam ti zato rekao da treba da vrati String pa onda da ga deserijalizujes ,ali dobro ako radi automatski :)