# How to parse json with dynamic keys using Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Here's the `JSON` where `jsonObject` key is dynamic :

```
{
  "CH000032": [
    {
      "type": "event",
      "details": {
        "programID": "MV10000032",
        "programType": "MOVIE",
        "title": "Titanic",
        "year": "1997",
        "rating": "PG-13",
        "durationSec": 11640,
        "startTimeSec": "",
        "endTimeSec": "",
        "language": "ENG",
        "isHD": true,
        "Genres": [
          "Movies",
          "Action"
        ],
        "description": "A seventeen-year-old aristocrat falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.",
        "imageUrl": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dte07foms/image/upload/c_scale,h_405,w_270/l_Copyright_e3jt1k/v1508831090/Titanic_b0hqo0.jpg"
      }
    }
  ],
  "CH000033": [
    {
      "type": "event",
      "details": {
        "programID": "EP10000132",
        "programType": "EPISODE",
        "title": "A Chic Bar in Ibiza",
        "seriesTitle": "Two and a Half Men",
        "seasonNumber": 12,
        "epsiodeNumber": 2,
        "year": "2014",
        "rating": "TV-14",
        "durationSec": 1260,
        "startTimeSec": "",
        "endTimeSec": "",
        "language": "ENG",
        "isHD": true,
        "Genres": [
          "Comedy",
          "Romance"
        ],
        "description": "Alan has second thoughts about getting married when Walden has him sign a prenup.",
        "imageUrl": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dte07foms/image/upload/c_crop,h_405,w_270//l_Copyright_e3jt1k/v1508831090/2AndHalfmen_splkro.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to parse this `JSON`.  Please let me know how should the class
 be written with `@SerializedName` annotation using `Retrofit`.

**Note** : `CH000032, CH000033 etc are dynamic.`

Comment: Use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate pojo from json response.

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati I already tried. It takes CH000032 as a class name which is not the case. Because It's dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse dynamic JSON with Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856975/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-with-retrofit)

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati My keys are dynamic bro :( So I don't know the class name in advance

Comment: @Rakesh check my answer use hashmap in model class that help for dynamic key :)

Comment: tell me if you have still any query

Comment: You can refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707564/how-to-automatically-generate-model-class-from-json-in-android

Comment: @Thientvse, POJO generator generates the class with names CH000033 etc, which isn't what I want. Because those are dynamic keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, ModelClassName>` in your model class for dynamic like below :-

```
public class Data {
    @SerializedName("your_key")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, ModelClassName> result;

    //....
}
```

this can help to parse dynamic key in retrofit.

Comment: What's YOURKEYNAME?

Comment: your main responce object keyname is used there

Comment: And what's that w.r.t the above json?

Comment: show me your full json resoponce i will tell you how your model class will be :)

Comment: The above provided one is the full response bro :) Please help

Comment: your parent object has no key ??

Comment: tell me your parent object key name

Comment: can you get this responce in string ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160908/discussion-between-subhash-prajapati-and-rakesh).

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking will take much work , instead a better approach will be to change the structure o json to something like this -

```
"data": [
    {
        "type": "event",

         "programID": "MV10000032",
         "programType": "MOVIE",
         "title": "Titanic",
         "year": "1997",
         "rating": "PG-13",
         "durationSec": 11640,
         "startTimeSec": "",
         "endTimeSec": "",
         "language": "ENG",
         "isHD": true,
         "Genres": [
           "Movies",
           "Action"
         ],
        "description": "A seventeen-year-old aristocrat falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.",
        "imageUrl": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dte07foms/image/upload/c_scale,h_405,w_270/l_Copyright_e3jt1k/v1508831090/Titanic_b0hqo0.jpg"

    },

    {
        "type": "event",

         "programID": "MV10000032",
         "programType": "MOVIE",
         "title": "Titanic",
         "year": "1997",
         "rating": "PG-13",
         "durationSec": 11640,
         "startTimeSec": "",
         "endTimeSec": "",
         "language": "ENG",
         "isHD": true,
         "Genres": [
         "Movies",
           "Action"
        ],
        "description": "A seventeen-year-old aristocrat falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.",
        "imageUrl": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dte07foms/image/upload/c_scale,h_405,w_270/l_Copyright_e3jt1k/v1508831090/Titanic_b0hqo0.jpg"

    }]
```

Comment: Any other way other than changing json?

Comment: yes, you can use the interceptor of retrofit to manually parse the json and create the model at runtime