# How to use Retrofit with general response in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

In my application I want use Retrofit for connect to server and I want call API. 
I used this APIs : [text](https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentation) 
And I want call this end point : `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=01coin&vs_currencies=btc`

In response show me such as below :

```
{
  "01coin": {
    "btc": 1.3651e-8
  }
}
```

This keys (01coin & btc) of json create from end point query. 
When change the coins, response also changed! and I can create response json in kotlin!

I called API such as below code in my application

```
@GET("coins/list")
    suspend fun getCoinsList(): Response<ResponseCoinsList>
```

**ResponseCoinsList :**

```
class ResponseCoinsList : ArrayList<ResponseCoinsList.ResponseCoinsListItem>(){
    data class ResponseCoinsListItem(
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: String?, // 01coin
        @SerializedName("name")
        val name: String, // 01coin
        @SerializedName("symbol")
        val symbol: String? // zoc
    )
}
```

How can I use response class with dynamic object of json in retrofit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse json with dynamic keys using Retrofit 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748006/how-to-parse-json-with-dynamic-keys-using-retrofit-2-0)

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank you for your help. but can you send to me code with my scenario ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your get api request in retrofit as below

```
@GET("simple/price")
    suspend fun getCoinPrice(
        @Query("ids") coinId: String,
        @Query("vs_currencies") currency: String
    ): Response<Map<String, Map<String, Double>>> }
```

and where you are calling your api update as below

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val coinId = "02coin" // Replace with your dynamic coin ID
    val currency = "py" // Replace with your dynamic currency

    val coinPriceResponse = apiRepository.getCoinPrice(coinId, currency)

    if (coinPriceResponse.isSuccessful) {
        val coinPriceData = coinPriceResponse.body()
        coinPriceData?.let {
            // Handle the response here
            val coinPrice = it.get(coinId)?.get(currency)
            Log.d("CoinPriceResponse", coinPrice.toString())
        } ?: run {
            // Handle the case where the coin price response is null
            Log.d("CoinPriceResponse", "Coin price data is null")
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the coin price request is not successful
        Log.d("CoinPriceResponse", "Failed to fetch coin price")
    }
}
```